# How to loop through all cases in switch if they are all true

Tags: php, switch-statement, case

I have a switch statement with 3 cases,like this:

```
switch($date) {
 case 1:
   echo "";
 break; 
 case 2:
  echo "";  
 break;
case 3:
 echo'';
break;   
default:            
 echo '';
break;
}
```

And i am wondering,if there is a way to loop through all cases if they are all true.But with using break,because if i am not using it,the cases wont work properly.So is there a way???

Comment: What do you mean 'loop through all cases'?

Comment: They cant all be true together in one run

Comment: How about 3 separate if() {} statements? That way, they will all fire if they are all true. However, you should post some more code so we can understand better what you need.

Comment: how can `$date` satisfy all three conditions? if `$date` is `1` and `2` and `3`? huh? unclear.

Comment: It can't; hence the requirement for this very is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use switch if you want to see if multiple things are true about the variable in question since the switch statement will cut out once one of the cases holds true (i.e. it won't continue to look to see if the other cases also apply to the variable).

If your goal is to test if multiple things are true regarding a variable, just use an if statement:

```
if ($date == X && $date == Y && $date == Z) {
    // Do something since all the conditions are met
}
```

Another possibility is to "fall through" your cases like this:

```
switch ($variable) {
    case 0:
        // Do something to (some) variable to indicate this case applies
    case 1:
        // Do something to (some) variable to indicate this case also applies
    case 2:
        // Do something to (some) variable to indicate this case also applies
        echo "WHATEVER YOU WANT TO ECHO"
        break;
}
```